# Play Framework 2 only recompiles at first request

Tags: scala, playframework

I am using PlayFramwework 2.1.1 with Scala and I have created a small test server that I run locally (`play run` from console). If I change something while the server is running, these changes won't be recompiled and "re-deployed" until the first request hits (`curl "http://localhost:9000"`, for example).

Is there a way to have the server refresh upon save, like on Tomcat? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep. Start it with `play ~run`. (notice the tilde.) That way, files will automatically be recompiled after saving them.

Answer (score 5):

That's common usage case

`play run` waits for request to compile changes (so compiles at the first request right after changes)

`play ~run` after change saving

Keep in mind that goes with price increased memory and CPU consumption, so while developemnt is not always desired situation.

Comment: I thing you're wrong: `play run` compiles after each requests. But it waits the next request before recompiling, unlike `play ~run` which check in real time file modifications.

Comment: Sorry, wrong spelling it should be "compiles after each first request, right after the changes" :)

Answer (score 0):

Also check out James Ward's [Play-auto-refresh](https://github.com/jamesward/play-auto-refresh), which  refreshes the browser upon save.